# Reduce $1819^5 \pmod {2669}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

With $2669= 17\cdot 157$, and $1819= 17\cdot 107$, by CRT I need to first solve $(17 \cdot  107)^5 \pmod {17}$ and $(17 \cdot 107)^5 \pmod {157}$.

I am having trouble with modulo $157$. Exponent $5$ is too small for Euler's theorem, or FLT. Is there some other ways to reduce $(1819)^5 \pmod {157}$ by hand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Shubhangi I believe the residue is 134...

Comment: oh yes , it is .. $( 1819 )^5 \equiv 92^5 \equiv -65^5 \equiv 14^2 \cdot -65 \equiv  196\cdot -65 \equiv 39 \cdot -65 \equiv  134 \mod 157 $  ( I misplaced the minus symbol :P )

Comment: Brute force gives $$1819^2\equiv1870\pmod{2669}\\1870\cdot1819\equiv1224\pmod{2669}\\1224\cdot1819\equiv510\pmod{2669}\\510\cdot1819\equiv1547\pmod{2669}$$

Answer (score 1):

First off, check whether $2669$ is prime.  Nope, it's divisible by $17$ giving the prime factorization $17×157$.

The $\bmod 17$ component is literally zero as $1819$ is also divisible by $17$.

So we turn to $\bmod 157$.  Here $1819\equiv248\equiv92$, and as one of the comments to the question says $\color{red}{\text{(Hey, No answering in comments!)}}$ the fifth power of this has residue $134$.

So we need to solve $x\equiv 0\bmod 17,x\equiv134\bmod 157$.  Since $17^{-1}\equiv37\bmod157$, CRT gives $\color{blue}{x\equiv134×37\equiv1547\bmod 2669}$.